# Proof of Cauchy–Riemann equations being same as $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar z}=0$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, cauchy-riemann-equations

I am new to complex analysis. Recently, I came across the statement that if $z=x+i\,y$, then for a function $f=u(x, y)+i\,v(x, y)$ satisfying Cauchy–Riemann equations, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar z}=0$. The proof is given below:

Using chain rule,
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar z}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial \bar z}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial \bar z}=0$$
Now, $x=\frac{z+\bar z}{2}$ and $y=\frac{z-\bar z}{2i}$. This gives us that $\frac{\partial x}{\partial \bar z} = \frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{\partial y}{\partial \bar z} =\frac{i}{2}$. Substituting these values in the equation above, we get:
$$\frac{1}{2}(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+i\,\frac{\partial v}{\partial x})+\frac{i}{2}(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+i\,\frac{\partial v}{\partial y})=0$$
Some simplification gives
$$(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}-\,\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}) + i\,(\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y})=0$$
This gives the Cauchy–Riemann equations.
However, I am a little unsure about the step where $\frac{\partial x}{\partial \bar z}$ and $\frac{\partial y}{\partial \bar z}$ are computed as they take $\frac{\partial z}{\partial \bar z}=0$. Since $\frac{\partial \bar z}{\partial z}$ is not defined (CR eqns are not satisfied), how can we take it to be $0$? Is the proof correct?

Comment: The operator is usually defined as $\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}} = \frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + i\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial z} = \frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x} - i\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)$. Everything from there falls from that definition. Another way to think about it is since we take $x$ and $y$ to be independent variables, then the formulas for $z$ and $\bar{z}$ define a change of coordinates, so we take them to be independent variables, too.

Comment: "Since $\frac{\partial \bar z}{\partial z}$ is not defined (CR eqns are not satisfied)" That's for $\frac{d\bar z}{dz}$. Partial derivatives are a lot less picky.

Comment: Following @NinadMunshi 's comment, see pages 1-3 here: https://www.math.uh.edu/~shanyuji/Complex/Complexgeometry.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Note that $${\partial z\over \partial\overline z}{={{\partial z\over \partial x}\over {\partial\overline z\over \partial x}}+{{\partial z\over \partial y}\over {\partial\overline z\over \partial y}}\\={1\over 1}+{i\over -i}\\=0}$$